# A geometric interpretation (angles) of mathematical expectation and covariance.

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability

I have a habit of understanding everything geometrically. In this case, the victim is probability theory.

I will assume that we are working on $L^2 (\mathcal{F})$, the space of integrable  random variables $X^2$, a Hilbert Space. Here we have a well defined inner product given by:

$$<X,Y> = E[XY]$$

Quickly, the inner product is directly related to angles. To be more specific, we have the following formula:

$$\cos (angle(X,Y)) = \frac{<X,Y>}{|X||Y|}$$

Decreasing the length of the vectors does not change the angle. So I will assume for now that I am working with unit vectors, so that:

$$angle(X,Y) = \cos^{-1} (<X,Y>)$$

Thus we can assume that the internal product measures angles.

All right, given all of this, I have some questions

- I can interpret $E(X)= <X,1>$ as the angle between $X$ and $1$, a constant random variable. But I have a hard time relating this geometric interpretation (using angles) to the statistical intuition we learned in school.
- The case of covariance is similar. We know that the covariance between X and Y tells us about or indicates the relationship of two variables whenever one variable changes. However, mathematically,

  $$Cov (X, Y) = Cov (X - \mu_X ,Y) = E[(X- \mu_X)Y] = Cov(X - \mu_X,Y) = angle(\bar{X},Y)$$
  Where $\bar{X} = X - \mu_X$. How can I link the $angle(\bar{X},Y)$ to the classical interpretation of the covariance?
- Something more dramatic is the case of variance. we know that variance measures the dispersion of possible outcomes of the random variable $X$. Assuming that $\mu_X = 0$, we have:
  $$Var(X) = Cov(X,X) = E[X^2] = <X,X> = |X|^2$$
  That is, the notion of dispersion is linked to the notion of norm.

Any light on 
  this?

Comment: A good set of notes on this subject can be found here: https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee126/sp18/projection.pdf. One subtlety which those notes don't address is that $\langle X,X\rangle=0$ implies that $X=0$ almost surely. So strictly speaking the vectors in Hilbert space are _classes_ of almost-surely equal random variables. For a more rigorous presentation, see section 20.2 of Fristedt and Gray's textbook. (And for an early instance of this viewpoint, I suggest http://www.jehps.net/Decembre2008/Finetti.pdf.)

Comment: Another point you may find notable: One has $E(\overline{X})=E(X-E(X))=E(X)-E(X)=0$ and therefore $\langle \overline X,1\rangle=0$. That is, the centered variable $\overline{X}$ is orthogonal to the constant r.v. $1$. This also means that $E(X)=\langle X,1\rangle$ corresponds to the scalar projection of $X$ onto $1$ (which, incidentally, is a unit vector).